# header() loads everything on same page ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

when I click login it loads home.php on index.php and looks very strange.. is it possible to make it redirect or erase everything on index.php then load home.php

```js
function login(){
 var name = $('input#answer').val();
 var pass = $('input#password').val();
 if( $(name) == '' || $(pass) == '' )
  $('#output').html('Please enter both username and password.');
 else
  $.post( ('php/login.php'), $('#myForm :input').serializeArray(), 
   function(data){
    $('#output').html(data);
    
 });
 $('#myForm').submit(function(){
  return false;
 });
};
```

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['users']) != ""){
header("Location: ../php/home.php");
}

require '../php/dbConnect.php';
    $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE username = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
    $response = mysql_query($query);
 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($response);
 
    if($row['password'] == md5($password))
    {
  
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
        header("Location: ../php/home.php");
    }
    else{
        echo("Wrong Credentials");
 }
?>
```

Comment: just make the redirection in JS after you read the response, not inside the PHP script

Comment: You are open to SQL injections and should update your hashing method. Also `$_SESSION['users']` != `$_SESSION['user']`, do you set the `user` index somewhere as well?

Comment: how do i check if login was successful on js ?

Comment: Check what `data` is. Have the PHP return `success` for a successful login.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['username'];
header("Location: ../php/home.php");
die();
```

You usually need to issue a `die()` command after the `header()` statement.